# purgecss CLI -c cannot find module purgecss.config.js

Tags: tailwind-css

- version: "^1.0.1"
- OS: Windows7

After running the following (through npm script or global purgecss installation)

> purgecss -c ./purgecss.config.js

I get this:

> Error: Error loading the config fileCannot find module '/D:\userdata\myusername\myapp/purgecss.config.js'

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Find this line of code in `purgecss.js`

```
path.resolve(process.cwd(), pathConfig)
```

and change it to

```
path.join(process.cwd(), pathConfig)
```

credit of this solution to *Alexander Hj*